# Why is there no forEach method on Object in ECMAScript 5?

Tags: javascript, foreach, ecmascript-5

ECMAScript 5's `array.forEach(callback[, thisArg])` is very convenient to iterate on an array and has many advantage over the syntax with a for:

- It's more concise.
- It doesn't create variables that we need only for the purpose of iterating.
- It's creates a visibility scope for the local variables of the loop.
- It boosts the performance.

**Is there a reason why there is no `object.forEach` to replace `for(var key in object)` ?**

Of course, we could use a JavaScript implementation, like _.each or $.each but those are performance killers.

Comment: This is a question better suited to people involved in the discussions of ES5/ES6.

Comment: Why does `for-in` need replacing? And why wouldn't an `Object.forEach` also be a performance killer? The hit mainly comes from invoking the callback function.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Well, it's pretty easy to rig up yourself.  Why further pollute the prototypes?

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
  var value = obj[key];
});
```

I think a big reason is that the powers that be want to avoid adding built in properties to `Object`.  `Object`s are the building blocks of everything in Javascript, but are also the generic key/value store in the language.  Adding new properties to `Object` would conflict with property names that your Javascript program might want to use.  So adding built in names to `Object` is done with extreme caution.

Array is indexed by integers, so it doesn't have this issue.

This is also why we have `Object.keys(obj)` instead of simply `obj.keys`. Pollute the `Object` constructor as that it typically not a big deal, but leave instances alone.

Comment: But having `Object.forEach` (not in prototype) would be nice.

Comment: Its not poluting IMHO. It's called consistency.  Other languages have it, JS is one of worst on that board. Simmilar actions and transformations done on diff kind of types work logically different and have totally diff syntax. One fo biggest bullshits you have to eat if you are organized in head, JS will screw you over

Comment: "Why further pollute the prototypes?" Why improve things? This answer is not helpful.

Answer (score 6):

1. `.forEach` *does* create variables just for the purpose of iteration... Just not ones you create, yourself.
   If you're using a shim, then they're JS variables in a closure, else they're likely in C++, or whatever the browser's native implementation is.
2. ES6 is getting `for ... of` which will iterate through whatever you pass it.
3. ES6 is also getting block-level variables (rather than function-scoped), using `let`, instead of `var`
4. You will be able to add iterators to specific kinds of objects in ES6 (ie: the objects you build to support iterators).

But the problem here is that ES5 was meant to preserve most of the syntax of ES3 (few new keywords, and no new keywords in regular-use).
Most of the additional functionality had to be method calls (prototyped, typically).
And arrays needed plenty of work, given how much more use JS has seen since ES3 launched.

Objects don't need a `.map()` / `.reduce()` ability, unless you're building VERY SPECIFIC objects, in which case, you're implementing those yourself.

Comment: `for...in` iterates over anything. As for `for...of`, it will only iterate over [Iterables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#The_iterable_protocol)

Comment: @theFreedomBanana Yes, the expected behaviour of `for...of` has changed a lot since this answer was written, half a decade ago. This was written when a lot of people were still using `obj.hasOwnProperty(key)`. Initial talks of `for...of` were to cover arrays and objects, and just do the right thing with both of them.

I'll look at updating it, some time tonight.

Answer (score 2):

You have to remember that every object in javascript inherits from `Object`. Not every object in javascript needs to have it's properties iterated. Those are mostly confined to data model objects. Adding the forEach method will only bulk up the prototype of **every** object unnecessarily.

If you currently see the Object and it's methods, they are present only to identify the object, or to distinguish one object from another.