# Calling forEach on a hash object

Tags: javascript

So, this works (at least in chrome):

```
var foo = {
    0: 'a',
    1: 'b',
    2: 'c'
};

//add a non-enumerable length property
Object.defineProperty(foo, 'length', {value: 3});

[].forEach.call(foo, function(val){console.log(val);}); //logs a b c
```

It even works if the keys are numeric strings instead of integers, as long as there is a length property. However, if the keys are non-numeric strings it fails silently. If some of the keys are numeric and some or not it works for the numeric ones and fails silently on the others. So my question is two-fold. First, why can't I do this with non-numeric strings (does the underlying implementation use an incrementing `for` loop? why is it smart enough to do type coercion on the keys then?)

I mean, javascript doesn't have real arrays, right? They're just hashtable lookups with integers as keys? So although I realize I'm stretching the language to the breaking point here, why can't this be implemented/hacked to behave in a properly polymorphic fashion?

Second question is, if this isn't supposed to/able to be made to work, who thought it was a good idea to have it fail **silently**? Why does this not throw an error?

Comment: Have you checked [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14929819/why-is-there-no-foreach-method-on-object-in-ecmascript-5)? As for shims, there's a plenty in popular libraries/frameworks; the easiest way out is using `forEach` on `Object.keys` instead.

Comment: You've got it just the wrong way round. JavaScript *does* have real arrays, but they are disguised as objects with strings as keys. There is no such thing as an "integer property name" in JS.

Comment: And regarding *javascript doesn't have real arrays, right?* part: well, it's a bit of [an overstatement](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/v8/).

Comment: @raina77ow: Yeah, I know __how__ to iterate a hash, I'm asking __why__ it behaves that way, I'm not terribly good at reading language specification docs. thanks for the clarification on the nature of js arrays. You too bergi, thanks.

Comment: @bergi so is that similar to how js wraps primitives?

Comment: @JaredSmith: No, it's a ToString cast. Whenever you access any property of an object (even of an array), the property name is converted to a string and treated as such. Of course, modern engines don't do that internally for arrays, but the semantics are the same. That's the reason why you get strings when you use a `for in`-loop on an array.

Comment: @bergi sorry, I meant that js wraps arrays as objects in a way similar to how it wraps strings and numbers as objects.

Comment: @JaredSmith: Kinda. More magic is involved, as arrays are actual objects that can hold other (non-numeric) properties that would need to be stored somewhere as well - in contrast to immutable primitives.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for the info. I still long for an elegant way to iterate objects-as-hashes, I hear we're getting the ability to extend the built ins soon. Still won't have the perf of native implementation though :(

Comment: @JaredSmith How about [for..of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) then?

Comment: @raina77ow yeah its much better than the current options, I __love__ that you can iterate over generators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only works with integer keys between `0` and `length` because `Array.prototype.forEach` is supposed to be used with array-like objects.

**Does the underlying implementation use an incrementing for loop?**

More or less. Its behavior is defined in [ES5 Section 15.4.4.18](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.18):

> 1. Let `O` be the result of calling `ToObject` passing the this value as the argument.
> 2. Let `lenValue` be the result of calling the `[[Get]]` internal method of `O` with the argument "`length`".
> 3. Let `len` be `ToUint32(lenValue)`.
> 4. If `IsCallable(callbackfn)` is `false`, throw a `TypeError` exception.
> 5. If `thisArg` was supplied, let `T` be `thisArg`; else let `T` be `undefined`.
> 6. Let `k` be `0`.
> 7. Repeat, while `k < len`
>
>    1. Let `Pk` be `ToString(k)`.
>    2. Let `kPresent` be the result of calling the `[[HasProperty]]` internal method of `O` with argument `Pk`.
>    3. If `kPresent` is `true`, then
>
>       1. Let `kValue` be the result of calling the `[[Get]]` internal method of `O` with argument `Pk`.
>       2. Call the `[[Call]]` internal method of `callbackfn` with `T` as the `this` value and argument list containing `kValue`, `k`, and `O`.
>    4. Increase `k` by `1`.
> 8. Return `undefined`.

**Why does it work with non array objects?**

It behaves like this by design:

> The `forEach` function is intentionally generic; it does not require
>   that its this value be an Array object. Therefore it can be
>   transferred to other kinds of objects for use as a method. Whether the
>   `forEach` function can be applied successfully to a host object is
>   implementation-dependent.

**Why is `callbackfn` not called for non numeric properties?**

It "fails" for non numeric properties because `forEach` is just an array method whose purpose is iterate array-like objects. If you want to iterate all properties of an object, you are supposed to use a `for...in` loop.

Comment: Okay, I see now. My little hack works only because I used sequential numeric keys that matched to length, `forEach` is just looping from 0 to `len - 1` converting to str and trying to access that property on the object. It won't work at all with non-sequential keys. Although you didn't address it directly it also explains why no err is thrown. Le sigh. Back to `Object.keys(obj).forEach()`.